# Use "tabs" in textarea field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, indentation

Is it possible to use "tabs"(indenting) in textarea using javascript. When tab button is clicked, the next form element is focused. But, i need to indent the text in textarea.

I am currently working in a project and any code with javascript or jquery will help me.

Comment: There's a number of scripts available to do that, but I would be cautious about using them. Here's [one](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=32317), and here's [another](http://ajaxian.com/archives/handling-tabs-in-textareas).

Comment: @Mike why would you be cautious?

Comment: @chromedude: I'd be cautious because using the tab key to produce indents in a text area is overriding the normal function of the tab key in most browsers, which is to move focus to the next field or link. It may therefore cause accessibility issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best plugin I've seen for this is the [Tabs in Textarea plugin](http://teddevito.com/demos/textarea.html).  You can try a demo [on its page](http://teddevito.com/demos/textarea.html).

The setup is fairly simple, since it has a simple *effect*:

```
$("textarea").tabby();
```

The thing that annoyed me most about other plugins was lack of <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, which this handles.  You *can* do this without a plugin, but I wouldn't in this case...it's be quite a bit of code yourself, depending on the functionality you're after.  TextRange operations in a cross-browser way are still a bit hairy under the covers, this is one of the times that a plugin is a better approach, IMO.

Comment: Fantastic, Nick; when someone solved a problem nicely with cross-browser support, let’s avail ourselves of it!

Comment: Provided links don't work anymore. Source and files can be found here now https://github.com/alanhogan/Tabby

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
<input onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 9) { this.value += '    '; return false; }">
```

Basically, when you press the keyCode 9 (which is the Tab key) I return false. This prevents from focusing another element on the page.

To mimic the Tab spaces I just add the spaces myself to the value of the input itself.

Comment: That's only going to work sensibly if the caret is at the end of the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: capture the tab key in keypress events and stop propagation. I m not sure if this will work consistently across browsers; give it a try!